# Swift alternative to this Obj-C pattern using @dynamic?

Tags: swift, xcode, dynamic, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In Obj-C, I sometimes used the `dynamic` keyword in controllers to make working with their custom views more convenient. In this example, I wouldn't need to typecast `self.view` every time I wanted to access a property or call a function:

```
// MyServiceController.m

@dynamic view;

-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = MyServiceView()
    self.view.delegate = self;
}

-(void)someFunc
{
    [self.view doSomething];
}

// MyServiceView.h

@property(nonatomic, strong)id<MyServiceViewDelegate> delegate;
-(void)doSomething;
```

Is there a way to achieve this with pure swift?

Comment: Not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: But if I’m understanding the question correctly, in Swift I’ll often define computed property to do what I want, e.g. `var serviceView: MyServiceView { return view as! MyServiceView }` (and in Swift 5.1, you don’t even need the `return).

Comment: @Rob Whoops, mixed up my Obj-C and Swift! Let me edit for clarity.

Comment: Computed properties are definitely one way to do this, but I was just curious about using `self.view` directly. It's not a big deal, but I wanted to see if it was possible.